# Convert Excel solver to java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to convert a Excel Solver solution to a java app

The excel solver is

```
Solver Parameters:
Set Objective: D24 to Max
By Changing Variable Cells: C4:C23
Subject to the Constraints:
C24 = B24
L24 <= N24
L25 >= N25
(non-negative)
GRG Nonlinear
```

I have been goggling for sometime and cannot find a java library to achieve this. Any ideas?

I have tried choco-solver http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/

```
    Solver solver = new Solver("my first problem");
    // 2. Create variables through the variable factory 
    IntVar x = VariableFactory.bounded("X", 0, 5, solver);
    IntVar y = VariableFactory.bounded("Y", 0, 5, solver);
    // 3. Create and post constraints by using constraint factories
    solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.arithm(x, "+", y, "<", 5)); 
    // 4. Define the search strategy
    solver.set(IntStrategyFactory.inputOrder_InDomainMin(new IntVar[]{x,y} )); 
    // 5. Launch the resolution process
      if (solver.findSolution()) {
            do {
                prettyOut();
            }
            while (solver.nextSolution());
        }
```

I am finding it difficult to relate this to the Excel solver functions, my math is not great

Comment: What have you  tried so far? Faced any particular problem?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: I don't think that reading the excel file is the problem but the actual problem solving/optimization.

Comment: poi.apache.org reads a excel sheet. What I need to do is the solver  problem solving/optimization in Java. Basically porting a excel sheet and solver to the web. The solver uses non linear GRG

Comment: If you show us some code of what you already have we may be able to help you

Comment: I have added some code

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Simplexsolver implementation in Apache Commons Math](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2009/06/introducing-apache-commons-math.html), but I can't say anything on performance or possible problem size. Finding non-propertery solutions for optimization problems, can be tricky because it is very difficult to efficently optimize large problem sizes and it is an ongoing field of research with only a hand full of good commerical/research solutions.

If you want to keep excelfiles as input you need to parse the data and convert it. For reading Excel files you can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: Apache commons math does not support non linear GRG

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for an API to read and write to microsoft documents, take a look at Apache POI:

http://poi.apache.org/
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: Apache POI is one of the best known frameworks for this job and I've had only good experience with it so far.

Comment: poi.apache.org reads a excel sheet. What I need to do is the solver  problem solving/optimization in Java. Basically porting a excel sheet and solver to the web. The solver uses non linear GRG